# what is the purpose of eav_entity_attribute table

Tags: magento2, eav, eav-attributes

in Magento i have seen entity table, eav_attribute table  and attribute table, which has links.

But i don't find any link to eav_entity_attribute. I want to know the purpose of the table

Answer (score 0):

Well, Magento is storing some model's data (ex. products, categories, customers) with EAV standard.

EAV means **Entity**, **Attribute**, (Attribute) **Value**, which means that data is stored inside database vertically.

For example product:

Product **Type Entity** is delegated inside `eav_entity_type` table with code `product`.

Product **Entities** are stored inside `catalog_product_entity` table.

**Attributes** definitions are stored inside `eav_attribute` table (regardless of entity type).

Attribute **Values** are stored inside `catalog_product_entity_TYPE` tables.

`eav_entity_attribute` stores links of attributes with entity types, attribute sets, attribute groups and saves sorting for them. So this is the place that saves attribute's information about place to show this attribute inside default product form. Data manipulation is stored inside `Magento/Eav/Model/ResourceModel/Entity/Attribute` class and corresponding Repository and Collection resource model classes.

Comment: Where eav_entity_attribute is being used?

Comment: Hi @KrishnanDaiva , I've updated my answer, please make your question more precisce, so I can answer more precisely.